# In which orgs is possible to upgrade managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, scratch-org

Is it possible to upgrade a managed package, not in main Dev Hub org and its scratches? I mean in some not related to the Dev Hub org. We have a git repository with code from the managed package and need to add some new functionality to the package but we don't have access to the Dev Hub org

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a First Generation Managed Package, you need to update the package in the Packaging Org. This will be a normal Developer Edition org. If you're using a Second Generation Managed Package, you need access to the Dev Hub org.